# How can I use higher order messages with Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `teacher` model and that `teacher` has a `belongToMany` relationship with a `student` model.

I want to leverage a higher order message function to `sync` a `student` to many `teachers.`

Usually I would do the following:

```php
$teachers = Teacher::limit(5)->get();
$student = Student::first();

$teachers->each(function($teacher) use ($student) {
    $teacher->students()->sync($student)
});
```

With higher order functions I should be able to do:

```php
// Throws error BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::sync does not exist.
$teachers->each->students()->sync($student);
```

Unfortunately due to how higher order messages work as defined inside of the class `HigherOrderCollectionProxy` the relationship `students()` will be executed returning a collection of all the students that teacher has instead of a belongsToMany relationship instance.

How can I use higher order messages with Laravel Eloquent relationships?

Comment: Have you tried maybe encapsulate it inside a method `$teachers->each->syncStudents($student);` ?

Comment: Yea that would work but it's not really what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse the logic.

```
$teacherIds = Teacher::limit(5)->pluck('id')->toArray();
$student = Student::first();

$student->teachers()->sync($teacherIds);
```